# React redux thunk and component rendering too early before actions

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm sending request to API and then saving the response to array for later use with thunk, but the problem is that my component is calling render function too fast before my action that saves the response from API to array.

The error that I'm getting is `"Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior"`. I set "isFetching" bool state accordingly true/false each action but the render function seems to completely ignore if I put like a condition `if isFetching is true then return <p>loading</p>` in render. The action thats responsible for setting data from API works and sets properly but then its already too late.

Question is how do I delay rendering the component so by the time it renders I already have the data saved to array and ready to work with?

UPDATE WITH CODE:

Action.js:

```html
import axios from "axios";
export let startFetch = () => {
    return {
        type: "START_FETCH"
    }
}
export let endFetch = (array) => {
    return {
        type: "END_FETCH",
        array
    }
}
export let fetchApi = () => {
    let url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/stats"
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(startFetch())
        return axios.get(url).then(
            (response) => {
                dispatch(endFetch(response.data))
            },
            (err) => {
                console.log(err);
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Reducer.js:

```html
export let fetchApiReducer = (state={isFetching : false, array : []},action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case 'START_FETCH':
            return {
                isFetching : true
            }
        break;

        case 'END_FETCH':
            return{
                isFetching : false,
                array : action.array
            }
        break;
        default:   
            return state;
    }
}
```

Container.js:

```html
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {fetchApi} from "../actions/adsActions"

class AdsList extends Component {

    componentWillMount() {
            this.props.fetchApi();
    }

    renderList(ad) {
        return (
            <a className="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start">
                <div className="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                  <h5 className="mb-1">{ad.text}</h5>
                  <small className="text-muted">{ad.date}</small>
                </div>
            </a>
        );
    }


    render() {
        if(this.props.isFetching == true) {
            return (<p>Loading</p>);
         } else if (this.props.isFetching == false && this.props.array.length >= 1) {
                return (
                <div>
             {this.props.array.map(this.renderList)}
            </div>
         );
    }
}


}
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        isFetching: state.isFetching,
        array: state.array
    };
}


function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return bindActionCreators({fetchApi: fetchApi}, dispatch);
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(AdsList);
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please provide some code to investigate the problem for people who wants to help. You do not delay the render, you will fetch data, fire an action creator, update your state. In your component you can check if there is data. If not do something else or do nothing, when data lands return the data.

Comment: I added code to OP

Comment: I am not seeing where you connected Container.js with your store in your code

Comment: What do you get console.log the isFetching right below the render()? Are you sure your whole actions and reducers working without any problem setting your state? Do you use Redux Devtools?

Comment: I have seen it, good

Comment: Ooops, I confused you with the OP :) Soryy. What have you seen? I did not get it :) Is your state OK? What is the output of console.log? Try to debug your app like that, just follow the data and be sure it is OK. As a learner when I hit a problem I follow this method. By the way, you don't need else/if in your render and you don't need to check isFetching again.

Comment: yeah right below render() function and it doesnt register. I can see everything work in the console with the redux logger atleast in terms of actions. fetchApi calls startFetch action which then changes state "isFetching" to true, then fetchApi makes GET request to the API and calls endFetch which saves the response to state and changes "isFetching" to false, but I have problem with using the saved data because it render function is being called too fast Im still new

Comment: Render function is call too fast but it re-renders once there is a change in state.

Comment: isFetching condition check in render seems to work as long as I dont call stuff that uses the array state that has stuff saved from API Ive been with this problem for hours googling + youtube for hours idk how to solve it.

Comment: but it doesnt re-render for some reason even though state is being changed with the "endFetch" action I dont know

Comment: You don't need the else/if and check the isFetching again in your render. One check is enough to render Loading part. After that you can return your actual component. But of course this is not the problem. If your state changes properly then your component should re-render. If it does not then there is a problem with your state. Try to put your whole code to http://codesandbox.io/

Comment: idk if its my fault or I cant import something thats one directory up on that site like "import AdsList from "../containers/AdsList"; and it cant find it even though its placed the same where I also have, tried many different variations but still so I dropped that site.... still dont know what to do the state doesnt get updated, I called console.log on all lifecycle components and only componentWillMount and componentDidMount get called so it never updates -.-